# Rearrange a string without using loop syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

So if I have a table with values:

```
ID
------
a1b2c3
ac2b31
db13a2
```

I want the result to look like this

```
Id
------
abc123
acb231
dba132
```

In other words, rearrange the string so that all of the characters appear first, followed by all of the numbers. Order is unimportant.

(And what I meant by no loop is, no traditional loop. I was looking at some CTE examples, but couldn't adapt them here.)

Comment: I have no idea what a "traditional loop" is in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string to get one row for each character, order it so numbers go last and all other characters go first and then rebuild the string.

Code below uses a numbers table to split the string and the for xml path trick to rebuild it.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID varchar(10)
);

insert into @T values
('a1b2c3'),
('ac2b31'),
('db13a2');

select X.X.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(10)') as ID
from @T as T
  cross apply (
              select C.C as '*'
              from dbo.Number as N
                cross apply (
                            select substring(T.ID, N.N, 1)
                            ) as C(C)
              where N.N >= 1 and 
                    N.N <= len(T.ID)
              order by case when C.C in ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') 
                         then 2 
                         else 1 
                       end,
                       N.N
              for xml path(''), type
              ) as X(X);
```

Result:

```
ID
----------
abc123
acb231
dba132
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! There are so many things in the above query that I do not even know it exists.
I'll go through this thoroughly to understand how it works, so that I can expand to use in other places as well
Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

On SQL Server vNext you can take advantage of the [`TRANSLATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775084.aspx) function to solve this. That version isn't generally available to the public yet but it might be useful one day or to inspire an answer from someone else.

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@ID, '0123456789', SPACE(10)), ' ', '') 
+ REPLACE(TRANSLATE(@ID, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', SPACE(52)), ' ', '');
```

[db fiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_next&fiddle=d8e4e107d1aa9593e572c1e936833d7c) for your three examples in the question.

On SQL Server 2012 you could solve your problem by applying the `REPLACE` function 62 times but there may be a more elegant solution:

```
DECLARE @T table
(
    ID varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T
    (ID)
VALUES
    ('a1b2c3'),
    ('ac2b31'),
    ('db13a2');

SELECT
    -- Remove numerics
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        T.ID, 
        '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', ''), '3', ''), '4', ''),
        '5', ''), '6', ''), '7', ''), '8', ''), '9', '')
    +
    -- Remove alphas
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        T.ID,
        'a', ''), 'b', ''), 'c', ''), 'd', ''), 'e', ''), 'f', ''), 'g', ''),
        'h', ''), 'i', ''), 'j', ''), 'k', ''), 'l', ''), 'm', ''), 'n', ''),
        'o', ''), 'p', ''), 'q', ''), 'r', ''), 's', ''), 't', ''), 'u', ''),
        'v', ''), 'w', ''), 'x', ''), 'y', ''), 'z', ''),
        'A', ''), 'B', ''), 'C', ''), 'D', ''), 'E', ''), 'F', ''), 'G', ''),
        'H', ''), 'I', ''), 'J', ''), 'K', ''), 'L', ''), 'M', ''), 'N', ''),
        'O', ''), 'P', ''), 'Q', ''), 'R', ''), 'S', ''), 'T', ''), 'U', ''),
        'V', ''), 'W', ''), 'X', ''), 'Y', ''), 'Z', '')
FROM @T AS T;
```